# Moving urllib.request.urlopen to requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.7, urllib

I have the following line in legacy code, that I would like to change to use `requests`:

```py
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url, data)
```

I was looking into the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) and was trying to figure out which HTTP method is being used by the `urlopen`, but I can't see anything about it. I've changed this line to the following one, as I've figured out initially from the server:

```py
response = requests.post(
    url,
    data=data,
    verify=False,
    headers={"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
)
```

When I ran system tests, I've noticed that the `urlopen` was also executing `GET` requests if the `POST` was unsupported (or the opposite). Do I understand it right? Is there an equivalent in requests for that?

I have to move to requests to be able to use `Mocker()` in my tests.

Comment: are you saying that the response you provided above is the **result** of this urlopen operation?

Comment: That's the replacement I've reverse-engineered from the server. But for other endpoints/servers it (`urlopen`) uses `GET` instead of `POST`. That's why I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [to urllib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request), the method (GET/POST) you're using is determined as follows:

- "The default is 'GET' if data is None or 'POST' otherwise."

Since the requests package doesn't have a function corresponding to `urlopen` that can do either GET or POST, a simple (simplistic?) way to migrate from `urlopen` would be to use `requests.get` when data is None, and `requests.post` if it's not.

Comment: Thanks, I've missed that part as I assumed that the `Request` object is to perform more sophisticated requests. I see that the `Content-type` is also different for the different HTTP methods.